# Saving data from Chrome extension popup to a rate-limited backend

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension as a popup.

The extension consists of a single textarea that always has focus. The user inputs some data, and we want that data to be saved to Firebase without the user having to explicitly save.

At the moment, I save the data periodically (detect every keystroke and after 300ms of idle, fire the save). But if the user closes the window before save is fired, I might miss some data.

So I was wondering if there is a way to detect the closing of the popup.
I have tried using `window.onunload` event but it doesn't seem to be fired.

Any suggestions? I was also thinking of using service workers to have a separate thread, but they don't seem to be available in Chrome extensions.

Comment: You can use service worker in a chrome extension but it won't help here. The popup context/environment is completely destroyed when it's closed. And even if you detect the moment it's closed by opening a port connection to the background script, it won't give you enough time to save the data. The modern method is to autosave the data on every change (maybe in a temporary key).

Comment: It looks like typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/393552). "Auto saving" may be done without "periodic saving". Just listen to appropriate events (e.g. [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) or [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)) and save the input when they fire.

Comment: I could listen to `change` event but that would be fired on every keystroke. And I didn't mention it, but I'm using Firebase, and in my case, I should avoid sending requests to Firebase too often... (here's why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756534)

Comment: _I could listen to change event but that would be fired on every keystroke._ That's not true. `change` fires mostly on focus change, not on every keystroke.

Comment: ok sorry that's not what I meant. Basically in my app there's only one input. It's just a textarea, there's no other inputs. So there is no "blur" and thus, no "change". That's why at the momentI only rely on "keyup", which I debounced at 300ms to avoid too many requests. I'll clarify this in the original question.

Comment: _I'm using Firebase, and in my case, I should avoid sending requests to Firebase too often._ It seems that you're trying to mix two _**separate**_ tasks in one: _saving input data_ and _sending them to server_. These tasks should be run _**separately**_: the 1st in popup, the 2nd - in background script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use `service worker`

Do this:

- if you don't have a background script,you need to add one
- add a `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` in the background script
- do not fire `save` option in the popup. listen to the `keyup` event in the popup, and send an event to the background with every `keyup` event.
- do your `wait 300ms and send data to firebase` stuff in the background

if you do not familiar with `chrome.runtime.onMessage` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, you need to read the SDK documentation.

Comment: That sounds like what I need : ) i'm gonna try this and let you know. thanks